# E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: "'%S-" in "select * from tb_inventory where SKU like '%S-"

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-studio

I created an inventory management application using SQLite. I get an error like this:

> E/SQLiteLog: (1) unrecognized token: "'%S-" in "select * from
> tb_inventory where SKU like '%S-"

This error occurs if the string I entered has a special character. how to handle it?

```
String productcodewithoutspace = productcode.trim(); SQLiteDatabase db = myDB.getReadableDatabase();
                String query ="select * from tb_inventory where SKU like '%"+ productcodewithoutspace +"%'";
                cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                    skuTextView.setText(cursor.getString(1).toString());
                    productNameTextView.setText(cursor.getString(2).toString());
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(PriceChecker.this, "Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                cursor.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use variables rather than entering raw data into the sql string:

```
String query ="select * from tb_inventory where SKU like '%' || ? || '%'";
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] { productcodewithoutspace });
```

where `||` is sql string concatenation and `?` is the variable.

Comment: Thank you for responding to my problem. previously I have tried as you recommend but what appears is a toast "Data not found" based on the code above. even though I make sure the ProductCode with that value is in my SQLite database.

Comment: in my case the data I entered is S-CSW83 and in SQLite Database I have ProductCode/SKU with value S-CSW83. if i use hardcode productcodewithoutspace="S-CSW83", all work fine! Its weird.